# How to handle Print event (via shortkey CMD + P) in Cocoa with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I tried this in AppDelegate. But after shortkey CMD + P the method never being called.

```
- (void)handleEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSLog(@"111111111");
}

[[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager]
    setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleEvent:withReplyEvent:)
      forEventClass:kCoreEventClass andEventID:kAEPrintDocuments];
```

Comment: Command-P in your app or Command-P in the Finder?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle the AppleEvent directly, take a look at the `NSApplicationDelegate` method [`application:printFiles:withSettings:showPrintPanels:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428713-application?language=objc). HTH

Answer (score 0):

⌘P is tied to the menu item titled "Print…". Triggering this menu item calls a particular responder chain message, which by default is `-print:` (see MainMenu.xib connections).

[image]

One simply needs to implement `-print:` somewhere along the responder chain to receive that message. By default, macOS applications have an implementation of `-print:` in `NSWindow` and so you'd have to either override this implementation to further it along the responder chain or implement it in a view/view controller subclass. As an example, this could be the implementation you have in an `NSView` subclass that is first responder or if you subclass `NSWindow`:

```
- (void)print:(id)sender {
    // viewToPrint is whatever NSView we want to use in the print operation
    [[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:viewToPrint] runOperation];
}
```

Also be sure to enable printing for your app's capabilities or else your app will complain that printing isn't permitted.